# ImageMagick outputs an empty image when using the `-morphology` paramter

Tags: server, imagemagick

ImageMagick outputs an empty image when using the `-morphology` parameter. I tried the same command and it is working well on other computers.

I uninstalled the lib and reinstall it, and even after uninstalling it I am able to call the `convert` command. I did a lot of tries and I even used the source with `make` and `make install` to install it, but I still get the same result: always an empty image.

I am using Ubuntu 16 Server.

Comment: Could you tell us: which version of Ubuntu et imagemagick you're using? As well as the command you're tying to run/how may we reproduce?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir
I was using 7 and after downgrading to 6.9 issue fixed
I really appreciate your support
Best regards

Comment: Good to know you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

> [...] I was using [ImageMagick version] 7 and after downgrading to 6.9 issue fixed [...]

<sup>Answer from OP's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181855/imagemagick-outputs-an-empty-image-when-using-the-morphology-paramter#comment1975678_1181855)</sup>